# ios how to send refreshToken from appdelegate to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I am a beginner in developing IOS app. Now i want to send a refreshToken data  from a method in AppDelegate to mainViewController.
i can't get it first time when download it. But second time i can get it.
i think it takes some time when it creation first time and it is stored after. 
Please help me, how to send data in a method from AppDelegate to ViewController. ultimately, i want to store it to database and send push notification message to user from serverside.
i use following code.

//AppDelegate.h

```
@class ViewController;
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) ViewController *myViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;     
@end
```

//AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)tokenRefreshCallback: (NSNotification *)notification {
NSString *refreshToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshToken);

//
if(refreshToken){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:refreshToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
// Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.

[self connectToFirebase];

}
```

//ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

//ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myViewController = self;

//get tokenId
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];
if(token){
    NSLog(@"i have token~!!!: %@ ", token);
}else NSLog(@"no token!: %@ ", token);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    

}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Ok so you are not getting token value first time, right?

Comment: What method is triggering the notification for `tokenRefreshCallback`?  It would appear to be asynchronous - so the first time you call it from your ViewController the token hasn't been set yet.  The second time, the callback has been called and the token saved.

Answer (score 0):

use NSNotifiactionCenter

in your Appdelegate when token is available post a notification with the token(add following code in app delegate where token is available)

```
 NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"token": @"YOUR_TOKEN"};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshTokenAvailale" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

And put this code in your main view controller

```
- (void) dealloc
{
// If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification   Center
// will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
// object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}

- (id) init
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
    name:@"refreshTokenAvailale"
    object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"refreshTokenAvailale"])
    {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSString* token = userInfo[@"token"];
    }

 }
```

Comment: There are three errors. 
first is in (object:self,userInfo:userInfo];) .
xcode says expected ']' between userInfo.
second one is in ([super dealloc];)
xcode says ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'.
last one is in( String* token = userInfo[@"token"];)
xcode says fix String to NSString
i couldn't run the project because of them. 
How could i do? Thanks

Comment: oops sorry mate. i'll just update the code in few minutes

Comment: @anichars please check the updated code, and comment if you face any problems. thanks

Comment: There are not errors anymore. Where can i check the refreshToken.
Help me do NSLog in somewhere. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @anichars you can find token in receiveNotification method inside your view controller. (NSString* token) is your token that you wants to use. you can do further code from there i.e. using token for api calls or storing it to server etc... also accept this post as answer if you found your solution thanks

Comment: Hi there, i added NSLog in your code.
    - (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
    {
     NSString* token;
    
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"refreshTokenAvailale"])
    {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSString* token = userInfo[@"token"];
        NSLog(@"This is myTokenId!! ID: %@", token);
    }
    NSLog(@"This is myTokenId!! ID: %@", token);
    
    }
i can't find Log in Debug area my token. sorry, i am a not good at it.